# How can one identify an organism from its dissymmetry ratio?

Tags: dna, classification

If I am given the dissymmetry ratio of an organism ((A+T)/(G+C) is a constant), how can I identify the source of the DNA and classify the organism?

Comment: What information have you found so far on your own?

Comment: @kmm uhh absolutely nothing **scratches head**

Comment: The point is that we need to better understand you motivation for trying to do this. What do you know, what do you need to know, etc. Take a look at the  tour to see how the site works: http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour Without more information, your question will likely be closed as either too broad or without sufficient information.

Comment: You cannot. That information is too little for identification.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what lineage (bacteria, virus, eukaryotes) you are interested in and what level of accuracy you are hoping to reach.

We know the (A+T)/(G+C) ratio for a handful of eukaryotes only. So if you were thinking about eukaryotes, there is no need to look much further. You cannot match a (A+T)/(G+C) ratio to a species because we don't know the (A+T)/(G+C) for the vast majority of species.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the (A+T)/(G+C) to those of higher orders; see "applications in systematics" on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GC-content

( While the (A+T)/(G+C) ratio doesn't provide enough resolution to identify the species, OP didn't ask for identification of species.)